# How to add font-face in piwik?

Tags: matomo

I install a piwik in my server. but i need add other font in piwik.

I don't use google fonts in my piwik.

How to add `@font-face` in piwik?

Answer (score 2):

Piwiki's default theme is Morpheus and uses LESS pre-compiled CSS. You will need to edit [theme.less](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/master/plugins/Morpheus/stylesheets/theme.less) and change the `@theme-fontFamily-base`. If you want to use `@font-face` then you need to add it to the base.less and theme.less adapting your [font-face code for LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338241/how-we-can-use-font-face-in-less), alternatively, use an plugin if you're not confident with LESS.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example-plugin which shows how to change the default font in piwik to Arial: https://github.com/piwik/plugin-ClassicFontTheme

You can write your on plugin which changes the font in the same way.